# How to Add Ringtones for iPhone X

Tags: iphone, ringtones

Do you know how you can add ringtones to your iPhone? I just noticed that my iPhone X has default ringtones still just like the older ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you're feeling creative, you can create your own ringtone using GarageBand.
When you're done simply tap the Share icon and then tap Ringtone.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the ringtones already on your computer, you can upload the ringtones to your phone by following the instructions in this [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207955):

> If you have a ringtone or tone in iTunes on your Mac or PC that you
>   want to move to your iOS device, you can manually add it to your
>   device using iTunes.
>
> 1. Connect your device to your computer.
> 2. Open iTunes. Make sure that you have the latest version.
> 3. On your computer, find the ringtone or tone that you want to add to your device. If the ringtone or tone previously appeared in your
>      iTunes library, you can find it in the Tones folder of your iTunes
>      media folder.
> 4. Select the tone that you want to add to your device and copy it. (You can use a keyboard shortcut.)
> 5. Return to iTunes and go to the Library tab of Music.
> 6. Click on your device in the left sidebar, then click Tones.
> 7. Paste your tone. (You can use a keyboard shortcut.)